# My ID is expired, can I fly to the Bahamas with my passport?

Tags: usa, air-travel, passports, paperwork

My driver license expired April 19, 2019, my flight to the Bahamas leaves August 25, 2019.

I have a passport, can I still fly using just my passport as an ID too?

Comment: Passports are generally accepted as ID, pretty much everywhere in the world.  However, to confirm, please state where you're flying from, and what country's passport you hold.

Comment: I am flying from San Diego CA and I hold a US passport

Comment: You can fly with your passport, but surely you can get a new driver's licence before August?

Comment: @NateEldredge I have a hard time believing that there is any situation in which a passport is not accepted as ID to fly but some other document is.

Comment: Yes. In fact, you _need_ your passport in any event. You can enter the Bahamas using an enhanced DL, but not by air travel.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I suspect that Nate Eldredge was getting at the possibility of visa requirements.  Anyone who was under the impression that a driver's license would be sufficient to fly to the Bahamas might also be overlooking visa requirements.

Comment: You don't plan to renew your driving license?

Comment: @phoog True but anyone who thinks a driving license is enough to fly to the Bahamas won't imagine that a comment that doesn't say "visa" is about visas.

Comment: "can I fly to the Bahamas with my passport?" No, you need a plane.

Comment: @DavidRicherby that is of course true.  I presume that the plan was to mention visas, if necessary, after receiving a response.  It seems that people often take that approach here when asking clarifying questions like that.

Comment: I'm confused. Are driver licenses (of any origin) considered a valid travel document anywhere?

Comment: @npst: Well, you generally need one if you're planning to travel by driving a car...

Comment: @Sean that's fair

Answer (score 36):

To fly to the Bahamas from the US as a US citizen, you [need a passport in any event](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Bahamas.html), and you [do not need any other ID](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification).  So a driver's license isn't particularly helpful for this trip, and its being expired is not a problem.

Comment: Unless the OP wants to drive while in the Bahamas...

Comment: @David yes of course.  I didn't mention that since the question asks about "ID" and did not mention driving, but it's certainly possible that there could be a misunderstanding about that.

Comment: True, he didn't mention it. But the temptation to make a bit of fun was irresitible.

Comment: Maybe he wanted to drive TO the Bahamas ;)

Comment: @qht Good idea!  I wonder what the licensing requirements would be for doing that in something like an [Amphicar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphicar).

Comment: @phoog That would be awesome! I guess it counts as a boat for immigration purposes.

Answer (score 21):

The whole point of a passport is to act as ID when you're travelling! If you have a passport, you don't need anything else.

Comment: It's somewhat unusual in the US even to *have* a passport; the number of US passports in circulation is slightly over 40% of the population of the US (of course, there are noncitizens living in the US and US citizens living outside the US), and that percentage has grown dramatically in the last 10 to 20 years.  It is not difficult to imagine a US citizen who hasn't ever thought of the possibility of boarding a flight without a driver's license.

Comment: Technically speaking, the _main_ purpose of a passport is to convince the officials of the nation you are visiting that there is some other place in the world to which you can return when they don't want you any more.

Comment: @SolomonSlow "Technically" according to whom? My passport says "Her Britannic Majesty's Secretary of State Requests and requires in the Name of Her Majesty all those whom it may concern to allow the bearer to pass freely without let or hindrance, and to afford the bearer such assistance and protection as may be necessary", not that Her Britannic Majesty's Secretary of State Promises to let this guy back in once you folk have had enough of him."

Comment: Hmm, maybe I should not have said "technical." Also, I'll have to dig out my U.S. passport. I remember reading the fine print once long ago, and I thought I came to the conclusion that it was a unilateral agreement, saying in its essence that, "we'll take this guy back." But maybe I misremember that. Or maybe, the fine print that any particular nation adds is just intended to give the document a weighty, "official" feel, and what other nations think the passport actually represents is entirely their own concern.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Most (all?) countries will allow their citizens to reenter. So at least part of the purpose of a passport is to demonstrate nationality and thus indicate where the person can be returned, if necessary. But I don't think that's the "_main_ purpose".